# Migrate parent pom to gradle in a spring boot project

Tags: gradle

In my spring boot project the pom.xml has a `<parent>` tag which refers to the parent pom.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.sintara.codify.ems</groupId>
        <artifactId>ems-parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
```

I am migrating my project from maven to gradle.

How do I take care of this  or parent pom concept in Gradle.

Is there any way to do it without converting it into a multi project setup.

Answer (score 0):

In gradle we have similar usage. We can create a `parent.gradle` file in project root path, and declare common dependencies in it. just like below:

```
ext {

    parent = [
            "ems" : "com.sintara.codify.ems:ems-parent-pom:1.0.0"
    ]
}
```

And then in your child gradle file, you can use it:

```
dependencies {
    implementation rootProject.ext.parent["ems"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In case I need to go with the approach of changing the parent pom file to its corresponding gradle file, how can I reference the parent gradle in the child gradle file. Is it doable at all?

Comment: If your parent.gradle is at project root path, you can reference it without any other work.

Comment: Sounds good! but the only problem being how good of a practice it is to have a parent gradle file in the child project's root path. Is it recommended?